# Japanese and Korean characters support Pyhthon

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, encoding, cjk

**I get character errors in pyhton when web scraping.**

```
from requests_html import HTML

with open('list.html', 'r', encoding='cp932', errors='ignore') as html_file:
    source = html_file.read()
    html = HTML(html=source)

video_link = html.find('a', first=True).text
print(video_link)
```

**The line it opens in html is this**

```
<dt><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAJn4XRhr10">
(15) アイナ・ジ・エンド (BiSH) / きえないで [OFFiCiAL ViDEO] - YouTube</a>
```

**The output I get:**

`(15) �A�C�i�E�W�E�G���h (BiSH) / �����Ȃ��� [OFFiCiAL ViDEO] - YouTube`

**The output I want:**

`(15) アイナ・ジ・エンド (BiSH) / きえないで [OFFiCiAL ViDEO] - YouTube`

**List html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE netscape-bookmark-file-1>
<html><link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Reading List</title>
</head><body><h1>Reading List</h1>
    <dl><p>
        </p><dt><dt><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAJn4XRhr10">
(15) アイナ・ジ・エンド (BiSH) / きえないで [OFFiCiAL ViDEO] - YouTube</a></dt>
```

**Setting the encoding on the python file to UTF-8 changes the output for the worst. (encoding UTF-8 in python file and charset UTF-8 in html file)**

**Setting the charset to cp932 and encoding in python file to cp932 changes the output for the worst.**

**Windows PowerShell**

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import sys

sys.getdefaultencoding()

'utf-8'
```

**I have the font to display the characters**

**Opening it in byte mode changes the output for the worst**

Comment: Please share the file. Posting its content in the question is not the same

Answer (score 0):

You may use a charset detection library to detect file encoding automatically. For example [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function).